# Set date and time for status notification

Tags: android

I'm using status notification in my android app and i want to create a notification that is fired on a date I have set. For example, I want to fire a notification tomorrow at 9 pm. When i try to set a date in the when parameter the notification just fires instantly instead of at the date and time that i set.

Your help would be most appreciated

Comment: Please [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) the below answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for that